# setting checkboxes which parent has a certain css class to indeterminate state

Tags: jquery

I have somewhere in my page a table that has a structure such as :

```
...<td class="ind"><input type="checkbox" .../> ... </td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" .../> ... </td> 
   <td><input type="checkbox" .../> ... </td>
```

For each checkbox contained in a `<td>` that has `ind` for a class, I would like to set that checkbox to its indeterminate state, as shown [here](http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/)

How can I get this piece to work ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var checkboxes = $(".ind").find(':checkbox');
        for (var i = 0; i < $(checkboxes).length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].prop("indeterminate", true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkboxes[i]` gives you the DOM node, and not the jQuery object, so you can't use `.prop` there. Either use `checkboxes[i].indeterminate = true` or `checkboxes.eq(i).prop('indeterminate', true)`

Of course the code can be simplified. You don't need to iterate over the checkboxes to set the property, you can set it immediately to the entire set, and jQuery will handle the iteration internally:

```
$('.ind :checkbox').prop('indeterminate', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a one-liner

```
$(".ind :checkbox").prop("indeterminate", true);
```

Note that jQuery always works on all selected elements. You don't need to write loops.

Answer (score 0):

.prop is a jQuery method, just $.each():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(".ind").find(':checkbox');
    // for (var i = 0; i < $(checkboxes).length; i++) {
    //    checkboxes[i].prop("indeterminate", true);
    // }

    checkboxes.each(function() {
        $(this).prop("indeterminate", true);
    });
});
```

edit: as tomlak said, this is actually a one liner :) since you can select all the wanted checkboxes via $(".ind").find(':checkbox'); you can simply continue doing jQuery awesomeness:

```
$(".ind").find(':checkbox').prop("indeterminate", true);
```